# How do I upgrade pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to upgrade pyinstaller to the latest version. I tried ' pip install --upgrade pyinstaller ' but it kept it at the same version. Right now I have pyinstaller 5.13.2, but I want 5.7. When I do ' pyinstaller --version ', it gives me 5.13.2.

Comment: _I want to upgrade pyinstaller to the latest version ... Right now I have pyinstaller 5.13.2, but I want 5.7_ Those statements seem to be in conflict. 5.7 is older than 5.13.2, and neither is the latest release (currently 6.3.0). Could you clarify which version you want installed? Also, what version of Python are you using? (by any chance, Python 3.7)?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I have a glitch in my pygame project exe where is crashes. I had someone else build the project for me using their pyinstaller, and it worked. Their version is 5.7, and mine is 5.13.2, so I assumed that since 5.7 is greater than 5.13.2, their version was the updated version.

Comment: Actually 5.13.2 is greater than 5.7, as 13 is greater than 7. So I assume you want to downgrade instead of upgrade?

Comment: "so I assumed that since 5.7 is greater than 5.13.2" - version numbers don't work the way you seem to expect them to (and they never have; this is a tradition of *how computers work* that goes back decades. People used to *have to* understand this even if they never wrote any code.)

Comment: Sorry my bad :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any error when tried the upgrade command?

Try this for a specific version `pip install --upgrade pyinstaller==5.7`